# Integral convergence and asymptotics

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Prove that $\int\limits_1^{+\infty} \frac{e^{\sin^2t}\sin{t}}{t}dt$ converges and that $\int\limits_x^{+\infty} \frac{e^{\sin^2t}\sin{t}}{t}dt = O(x^{-1})$ as $x \longrightarrow +\infty$

I solved the first part. Because its quite obvious that numerator antiderivative is limited and 1/x is monotonous, so we can apply Dirichlet's test. But I am having huge troubles with the second part

I tried integrating by parts, but it only makes integral more complex. I tried doing smth like $\int\limits_1^{+\infty} \frac{t}{t} \cdot \frac{e^{\sin^2t}\sin{t}}{t}dt$, because it seems that we want to have $\frac{1}{x}'$ somehow to have $O(x^{-1})$ but it also gave no result. Online calculator gives a solution with a Error function, but I wonder if there is an adequate solution.

Would be thankful for any help.

Comment: $e^{\sin^2(t)}$ is confined to $[1,e]$ so it does not change the convergence or big Oh notation at all.

Comment: Just out of curiosity : could you tell me where and/or how you obtained a solution with the error function ? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Integration by parts, and the error function, are very relevant things here.

Let $f(z)=\int_0^z e^{1-y^2}\,dy$, then $e^{\sin^2 t}\sin t$ is the derivative of $-f(\cos t)$. Now IBP gives $$\int_x^\infty\frac{e^{\sin^2 t}\sin t}{t}\,dt=\frac{f(\cos x)}{x}-\int_x^\infty\frac{f(\cos t)}{t^2}\,dt.$$

Since $y\mapsto f(\cos y)$ is bounded, both terms on the RHS are indeed $\mathcal{O}(x^{-1})$.